# store elements in url as seprate variables

Tags: javascript, url

suppose I have a URL: `https://whatever.com/#-Mquighthj23jjsn---12384959`
How do I store `-Mquighthj23jjsn` and `12384959` in two seperate variables
in javascript ???

Answer (score 2):

You can get the whole hash from the current url by calling `window.location.hash`, so in your case you could get those variables in array like this:

```js
const urlVariables = window.location.hash.substring(1).split('---');
```

So in result you'll have an array with `-Mquighthj23jjsn` and `12384959`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a correct way to pass parameters in URL, because if we add or remove any parameter in the future, the code could break.
As per standard URL parameter should be in Key Value Pair & separated with **&** characters.
for example - https://abc.xyz/category?xyz&page?10.

Here is the code on how can you get parameter values by their key.

```
var url = new URL(window.location.href);
var c = url.searchParams.get("category");
var p = url.searchParams.get("page");
console.log(c);
```